# Action to destroy user session is not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
Rails 3.2
```

In my views/options/_form.html.slim, I have the following:

```
= link_to 'Reject And Exit', destroy_user_session_path, :class => "btn btn-warning btn-lg"
```

When I run the application,  right click on the button, and copy the link, I get:

```
http://test.MyApp.com/users/sign_out
```

But when I click on it, I get the following message:

```
Unknown action
The action 'show' could not be found for UsersController
```

Any idea what's going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From documentation [UrlHelper#link_to](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v3.2/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to):

> Supported verbs are `:post`, `:delete` and `:put`. Note that if the
>   user has JavaScript disabled, the request will fall back to using
>   `GET`.

So in your case you have to specify the `method` for your link_to, otherwise it'll make a GET request which will redirect you to the show method, because are the same paths, but that use different HTTP verbs, try with:

```
= link_to 'Reject And Exit', destroy_user_session_path, :class => "btn btn-warning btn-lg", method: :delete
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't specify the HTTP verb it the action will default to a `GET` request from `show`. You need:

```
= link_to 'Reject And Exit', destroy_user_session_path, :class => "btn btn-warning btn-lg, method: delete"
```